# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality with a twist

Tags: vectors, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let u and v be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ .

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality states that $|u · v| ≤ |u||v|$

We are able to transform the above inequality so that it also shows us that

$|u+v|≤|u|+|v|$

But I cannot find a way to show that $\mathbf{|u-v|≤|u|+|v|}$

even though I now this has to be true. Any ideas?

Comment: ${}u-v=u+(-v).$

Answer (score 1):

$$|u+v| \le |u| + |v|$$
is shown already, so let's use this.
$$|u-v| = |u +(-v)| \le |u| + |-v| = |u| + |v|$$
and we're done.